# A thread holding multiple lock goes into wait() state. Does it release all holding locks?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote this program to check if a thread t1 holding lock on two different objects :
Lock.class and MyThread.class goes into waiting mode on MyThread.class instance using MyThread.class.wait().It does not release lock on Lock.class instance. why so ? I have been thinking that once a thread goes into wait mode or it dies it releases all the acquired locks.

```
public class Lock {

protected static volatile boolean STOP = true;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(myThread);
    t1.start();
    while(STOP){
    }
    System.out.println("After while loop");
    /*
     * 
     */
    Thread.sleep(1000*60*2);
    /*
     * Main thread should be Blocked.
     */
    System.out.println("now calling Check()-> perhaps i would be blocked. t1 is holding lock on class instance.");
    check();
}

public static synchronized void check(){
    System.out.println("inside Lock.check()");
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("inside Lock.Check() method : CurrrentThreadName : "+ threadName);
}
}


class MyThread implements Runnable{
public MyThread() {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("inside Mythread's run()");
        classLocking();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static synchronized void classLocking() throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("inside Mythread.classLocking()");
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("inside MyThread.classLocking() : CurrrentThreadName : "+ threadName);
    /*
     * outer class locking 
     */
    synchronized (Lock.class) {
        System.out.println("I got lock on Lock.class definition");
        Lock.STOP = false;
        /*
         * Outer class lock is not released. Lock on MyThread.class instance is released.
         */
        MyThread.class.wait();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that it doesn't release the other lock. As for why, it's because it isn't safe to do so. If it was safe to release the outer lock during the call to the inner function, why would the inner function be called with the other lock held at all?

Having a function release a lock it didn't acquire behind the programmer's back would destroy the logic of synchronized functions.

Comment: .Thanks for reply. once t1 goes into wait mode and not active any more why does it hold lock on Lock.class instance.

Comment: @ManishBhunwal when a thread is sleeping it doesn't mean it loses everything and that's why deadlock could happen if it holds another lock and waits without releasing it.

Comment: A function can indeed easily release a lock it didn't acquire: `synchronized void a() { b(); } void b() { wait(); }` -- it is `b` that releases the lock acquired by `a`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Right, but that's only because `a` and `b` are part of the same interface and thus have to be designed as a unit.

Comment: @ManishBhunwal: To prevent other threads from accessing it. If it was safe for other threads to access the object, why would it have been holding the lock at all?

Comment: `b()` could be anywhere: `public class A { public static final Object lock l = new Object(); public void a() { synchronized (l) { B.b(); } } } public class B { public static void b() { A.l.wait(); } }` This is terrible design, but disproves your logic which talks about the specified behavior of `wait`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I don't follow how it disproves my logic. Yes, you can do something stupid if you try hard enough. That doesn't change the reasons the interface is designed as they are. It doesn't enforce its rationale, but it has the rationale it has and is designed around that rationale. If `wait` released any lock other than the one specified, that would defeat the rationale. Yes, if you try hard enough, you can defeat the rationale, but it's not broken by design.

Comment: In that case your last sentence is just not what you intended to say.

Comment: I think I clarified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of wait() is that the Thread invoking it notices that a lock was already acquired by another thread, gets suspended and waits to be notified by the thread holding the lock when the latter one releases it (and invokes notify).  It doesn't mean that while waiting it releases all the locks acquired. You can see the wait's invocations as a number of barriers the thread meets on the way to acquiring all the locks it needs to accomplish an action.

Regarding the question "Why a thread doesn't release all the locks acquired when invoking wait" , I think the answer is that, doing so would make it more prone to starvation and it would also slow down the progress in a multithreaded application (All threads would give up all their locks when invoking the first wait and would have to start over when they acquire the lock they are currently waiting for. So, they would be in a permanent battle for locks.
Actually, in such a system, the only thread able to finish execution would be the one which manages to find all locks free when it needs them. This is unlikely to happen)

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDoc of method `wait()`

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread *releases ownership of **this monitor*** and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is working correctly. A thread goes into waiting status releases the corresponding lock instead of all locks. Otherwise think about that: if things are like what you thought, then when a thread waits it loses all the acquired locks, which makes advanced sequential execution impossible.