# Correct BoundedBuffer Implementation in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Saw couple of online example about bounded buffer. Not happy with their implementation. I am relatively new to Java. Any good suggestions or comments on the improved version? Thanks. 
For example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.List;

public class BoundedBufferNotGood {
    private final List<Integer> data;
    private final int capacity;
    private int size;
    private int head;
    private int tail;

    BoundedBufferNotGood(int capacity) {
        this.data = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        size = 0;
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void put(Integer x) throws InterruptedException {
        while (size == capacity) wait();
        data.add(head, x);
        head++;
        head %= capacity;
        size++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Integer get() throws InterruptedException {
        while (size == 0) wait();
        Integer x = data.get(tail);
        tail++;
        tail %= capacity;
        size--;
        notifyAll();
        return x;
    }
}
```

This code will work, but it is very bad on the unnecessary sleep and wakeup side. wait() function in put() and get() is waiting on the same condition **this**. But they should wait for different one. In get() method, wait() should wait for size > 0, and put() should wait for size < capacity.

Improved version:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.List;

public class BoundedBuffer {
    private final List<Integer> data;
    private final int capacity;
    private int size;
    private int head;
    private int tail;
    private final Object dataCV = new Object();
    private final Object spaceCV = new Object();

    BoundedBuffer(int capacity) {
        this.data = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        size = 0;
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void put(Integer x) throws InterruptedException {
        while (size == capacity) {
            synchronized (spaceCV) { // do we need to move synchronized() outside of while loop?
                wait();
            }
        }
        data.add(head, x);
        head++;
        head %= capacity;
        size++;
        dataCV.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Integer get() throws InterruptedException {
        while (size == 0) {
            synchronized (dataCV) {
                wait();
            }
        }
        Integer x = data.get(tail);
        tail++;
        tail %= capacity;
        size--;
        spaceCV.notifyAll();
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use implementations of `BlockingQueue` interface in `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: Actually they are still wait on the same lock `this` because your `wait()` is equals to `this.wait()`. `wait()` will not release all locks it obtained, you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494542/a-thread-holding-multiple-lock-goes-into-wait-state-does-it-release-all-holdi)

Comment: @user1861417 As Nier indicated although you have defined `spaceCV` and `dataCV` objects you are still waiting and notifying on `this` object and it is no different from your earlier version. And having these two objects doesn't help because `wait` and `notify` should be invoked on the same object. If you really are looking for an approach to have two different objects to be used for `wait` and `notify` have a look at [Condition API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). This link does have a sample code that meets your requirement.

Comment: Good point. Thank guys. That is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> wait() function in put() and get() is waiting on the same condition

Use a `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` instead of using `synchronized`.

The advantage of `ReentrantLock` is that you can obtain two (or more) condition variables from the same lock object, so you can have one condition for producers to wait on, and a different condition for consumers, but everybody locks the same lock.

Use

```
Lock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

to create the lock object, and then use

```
Condition producerCondition = myLock.newCondition();
Condition consumerCondition = myLock.newCondition();
```

to create the two condition variables.

Then you can use:

```
myLock.lock();   //instead of entering a synchronized block,
myLock.unlock(); //instead of leaving the synchronized block,

consumerCondition.await();   // instead of this.wait();
consumerCondition.signal();  // instead of this.notifyAll();
```

etc.

Hint:  Use a `try { ... } finally { ... }` to make sure that the lock gets unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the folks. The new version using Condition.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class BoundedBuffer {
    @GuardedBy("lock”) private final List<Integer> data;
    @GuardedBy("lock”) private final int capacity;
    @GuardedBy("lock") private int size;
    @GuardedBy("lock”) private int head;
    @GuardedBy("lock”) private int tail;

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition spaceCondition = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition dataCondition = lock.newCondition();

    BoundedBuffer(int capacity) {
        this.data = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        size = 0;
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
    }

    public void put(int x) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (size == capacity) {
                spaceCondition.await();
            }
            data.add(head, x);
            head++;
            head %= capacity;
            size++;
            dataCondition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int get() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (size == 0) {
                dataCondition.await();
            }
            int x = data.get(tail);
            tail++;
            tail %= capacity;
            size--;
            spaceCondition.signalAll();
            return x;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```